# JavaScript click again did hide

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this:
when I click, the img will showup, but it won't hide when I click again.

```js
var simon = document.getElementById("simon");

simon.addEventListener("click", picLink);
function picLink() {
  var allImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");

  for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
    allImages[i].className = "hide";
  }
  var picId = this.attributes["data-img"].value;
  var pic = document.getElementById(picId);
  if (pic.className === "hide") {
    pic.className = "";
  } else if (pic.className ==="") {
    pic.className = "hide";
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>Pictures</h4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-img="simon-pic" id="simon">Simon Cowell</a></li>
  </ul>
<img class="hide" id="simon-pic" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"/>
```

When I "click again....`<p>` didn't hide. Why? And how to hide `<p>` again?

Comment: *"When I "click again....<p> **did** hide."* - Do you mean "did **not** hide"? Because if it *did* hide why are you asking how to hide it again? It seems to me that your `for` loop will set all of the elements in question to have the `"hide"` class, so then the `if` condition will always be true.

Comment: I mean, when I click the <a> (not <p>)... the img show up, but I need to click other img that current img will hide.. , have any function or way to write, let that same click to hide the current img?

Comment: Sorry...... I'm new there
thank you for correct me .

Comment: click first time it show up, second time for the some <a>, it did not hide

(thank you for correct me~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `for` loop in your callback function is giving all images the `hide` class before you begin checking what the current class is.

This should be placed outside of the callback function, so it should only be executed once, to hide the images initially, not on every click event.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
  allImages[i].className = "hide";
}
```

```js
var simon = document.getElementById("simon");

var allImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
  allImages[i].className = "hide";
}

simon.addEventListener("click", picLink);

function picLink() {

  var picId = this.attributes["data-img"].value;
  var pic = document.getElementById(picId);
  
  if (pic.className === "hide") {
    pic.className = "";
  } else {
    pic.className = "hide";
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h4>Pictures</h4>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-img="simon-pic" id="simon">Simon Cowell</a></li>
  </ul>
<img id="simon-pic" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var simon = document.getElementById("simon");

simon.addEventListener("click", picLink);

function picLink() {
  var picId = this.attributes["data-img"].value;
  var pic = document.getElementById(picId);
  if (pic.className === "hide") {
    pic.className = "";
  } else if (pic.className === "") {
    pic.className = "hide";
  }
}

var allImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
  allImages[i].className = "hide";
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h4>Pictures</h4>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" data-img="simon-pic" id="simon">Simon Cowell</a></li>
</ul>
<img id="simon-pic" src="http://pg" />
```

Move the images init code out of the `click` callback.